# non-pure constant which increases by 1 for each evaluation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purely-functional

I'm very new to Haskell and trying to understand the basics of functional programming. I need to create a non-pure constant `next_nat :: Integer` which on first evaluation results in `0` and then increases by `1` for each evaluation. I then also need to call this as a parameter on a pure function `f` like `f next_nat` and check the result depending on argument evaluation.

I'm not sure how to do this. How can I increase it for each evaluation? Do I need other variables for this task? I only came up with this at the moment:

```
next_nat :: Integer
next_nat = 0

f :: Integer -> Integer
f x = x+1
```

I don't think this is right in this way..

Comment: You can't, not if it's simply an `Integer`. That's part of what "purely functional" means. There are ways to have a mutable variable in Haskell but then the type system needs to warn users of the potential mutability - a "pure type" such as `Integer` is strictly immutable.

Comment: You can use `succ` instead of `f`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, what you are asking for is a bit contradictory. As mentioned by Robin, if the type is Integer, the value will always be the same in Haskell.

As you say the answer has to be "*non-pure*", a possible solution is to involve the IO monad. That is, you would have to house your mutable entity in the "external world", that is the IO monad as far as the Haskell runtime is concerned.

Something like this:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 
Prelude> import Data.IORef
Prelude Data.IORef> mv <- newIORef ((0)::Integer)
Prelude Data.IORef> let next_nat = do { val <- readIORef mv ; modifyIORef' mv (\x -> 1+x) ; return val ; }
Prelude Data.IORef> 
Prelude Data.IORef> next_nat
0
Prelude Data.IORef> next_nat
1
Prelude Data.IORef> next_nat
2
Prelude Data.IORef> next_nat
3
Prelude Data.IORef>
```

More details in the [Data.IORef](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) documentation.

Typing infos:

```
Prelude Data.IORef> :t mv
mv :: IORef Integer
Prelude Data.IORef> :t next_nat
next_nat :: IO Integer
Prelude Data.IORef>
```

Comment: The task says: "Consider an extension of Haskell by a single non-pure constant `next_nat :: Integer`, which on first evaluation results in 0, then results in 1, in 2, etc". For me it is contradictory too, because constants should be immutable. Any idea what that means?

Comment: @Felix: it is a variable sort of constant then :-) No, formally this has to be an IO action returning an Integer value. It  __cannot__ be called a constant, I agree with the other commenters on that point. The language used is faulty. If the type is really Integer, it will always be the same value.

Comment: @FelixErlacher some wider context would be helpful, but to me the phrase "consider..." makes it clear that it's talking about a hypothetical (not actually existing) "extension" of Haskell which would allow you to do this. I presume to then point out how this would break a lot of the things Haskell relies on - but as I said, the context is missing.

Comment: Ok then I probably don't even understand the task... This is the rest of the task description: "Define a single pure Haskell function f in a
script, i.e., in the script next_nat must not appear, such that the evaluation of the expression f next_nat evaluates to at least three different values, depending on whether one uses call-by-value, call-by-name, left-to-right
argument evaluation or right-to-left argument evaluation." Any idea?

Comment: I know about call-by-name, call-by-value. But not much about the pure haskell function stuff in combination with this task.

Comment: @Felix It is obscure for me too. You might start by asking to the powers that be how comes left-to-right versus right-to-left evaluation can be relevant if f has a single argument, and also what is the accepted set of types for f.

Comment: I think i found a solution:

`f :: Integer -> Integer
f x = do
    let unused_var = x
    (x - 1 + 1)`

This should be the results:
call-by-value: 1
call-by-name: 0
left-to-right: 1 or 0 (depending on call-by-value or call-by-name is used)
right-to-left: -1 or -2 (depending on call-by-value or call-by-name is used). 
Is this correct?

Comment: @Felix At this point I think you would be better off just asking a __new__ SO question, this time about __f__ not next_nat. That might attract answers from Haskell people who have suffered thru this kind of rather theoretical exercises before.